# How to have an enum or enum-like class that can store an invalid enum value?

Tags: java, enums, java-11

Let's consider the following enum:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum Quality {
    GOOD(1),
    BAD(2);

    private final int value;
}
```

The enum is an abstraction over the `Quality` field given by the third party.
Working on socket programming here. Essentially `Quality` is a 4 byte integer on a TCP packet.

Now there can be unknown cases where `Quality` is an unknown value. Say 3. Now 3 doesn't correspond to either `Quality.GOOD` or `Quality.BAD`.

So the expectation is that, we translate the field to the enum (or enum-like object) but ensure if it is invalid then it retains the original value `=3`.

So expectation from the enum is like:

```
// Stateless API abstraction over third party
int value = parseTCPObjectForQuality();
Quality quality = Quality.fromValue(value);
publishQuality(quality);
```

```
// Application
Quality quality = receiveQuality();

// Now behaves like an enum
switch(quality) {
    GOOD: // dosomething.
    BAD : // dosomething.
    default: {
       // log error maybe.
       log.err(quality.getValue());       
    }
}

// And a isValid() function

if (!quality.isValid()) {
    // log error maybe.
    log.err(quality.getValue());   // prints 3  
}
```

How can we do this?

Comment: I would say a sealed class hierarchy (standardized in Java 17) and "pattern matching for switch" (preview feature in Java 17, 18, and 19) is the solution. But half that solution is still in preview, and you've tagged this question [tag:java-11]...